# C# Console.Out() doesn't write if interrupted

Tags: c#, console-application, filewriter

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;

FileStream ostrm;
    StreamWriter writer;
    TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
    try
    {
        ostrm = new FileStream ("./Output.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        writer = new StreamWriter (ostrm);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Output for writing");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return;
    }
    foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", envVar["Name"]);
    }
    Console.SetOut (writer);
    foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", envVar["Name"]);
    }
    Console.SetOut (oldOut);
    writer.Close();
    ostrm.Close();
Console.WriteLine("" +
Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have this code in a console application and it takes AGES to complete writing all the users on the network, and if it gets interrupted at any stage the Output.txt ends up empty. Is there any way to make it save periodically so that if anything happens I have usernames in the text file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Console.Out.Flush();`?

Comment: I've edited and compiled, but I won't be able to test it until Monday, thanks for the help anyways :D I'll be sure to let you know if it works how I want it to :)

Answer (score 0):

The program seems to be doing the same job twice. Also, instead of redirecting `Console.Out` try using `File.AppendAllText` like so:

```
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get()) {
    string str = string.Format("Username: {0}\r\n", envVar["Name"]);
    File.AppendAllText("./Output.txt", str);
}
```

AppendAllText will open and close file on each write, so it might be slower but much more reliable.